# Do we need to mark encryption as yes, if we are using zip archive with password protection

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Hi we use [zip archive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) lib by mattconnolly, we use it to create a backup zip of all the data(Photos,Videos,Notes and Db) in the application with password protection. So do we need to mark encryption as yes while submitting the app to iTunes Store.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your application to run like that (without encryption) then you can submit it without encryption. If it is the feature of your application to encrypt data then submit the application with encryption because the application which you will submit to iTunes will be the same which will be available to the end user for use.

Comment: No, I meant that does by using zip archive with password, does our app qualifies for export compliance that itunes connect ask us while submitting. 
i.e does zip archive uses encryption like AES or just compress the files.

Comment: Nope, the archive goes the same way it is build in Xcode, or when uploading with Application uploader. Any encryption can result in rejection of application. But why you need encryption?